# PHP email sending not working all the time

Tags: php, email

I really need someone's help. I am into this third day and cant understand what is the problem.

So, i have a php file which sends email as HTML after some action, the problem is very funny, it actually works good, but when i try to change some text inside the message, its not working. And if I ctrl-z and upload again to server it works.

For example this will work:

```
$message .='<p style="margin-top: 30px;">Ждём Вас 26.02.2016 в 10:30</p>';
```

If I change to:

```
$message .='<p style="margin-top: 30px;">Ждём Вас 26.02.2017 в 10:30</p>';
```

(from 2016 to 2017) its not sending email. no errors. nothing.

Andy ideas?

Comment: what's your character set?

Comment: What email system are you using, is it Exchange or something else?

Comment: check your mail system logs

Comment: I use UTF-8 and aolso tried BOM, no fix

Comment: My system log is: Router: smarthost_regular
Transport: remote_smtp_smart_regular
Out Time: Feb 13, 2017 2:38:14 PM
ID: 1cdFtS-00240N-7y
Delivery Host: smtp.antispamcloud.com
Delivery IP: 94.75.244.162
Size: 2.95 KB
Result: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 CV=yes: SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 550 High probability of spam

Comment: However why if i change back to 2016 it works?